# Add and Remove Class JQuery together

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have 3 fields as follows:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-regex="Phone is not correct" data-val-regex-pattern="(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}" data-val-required="Phone is required" id="Phone" maxlength="14" name="Phone" tabindex="5" type="text" value="" class="input-validation-error">

<input data-val="true" data-val-regex="Alt. Phone is not correct" data-val-regex-pattern="(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}" id="AltPhone" maxlength="14" name="AltPhone" tabindex="6" type="text" value="" class="input-validation-error">

<select id="BestTimeToCall" name="BestTimeToCall" tabindex="8" class="valid"><option value="Right Now">Right Now</option>
<option value="Morning">Morning</option>
<option value="Afternoon">Afternoon</option>
<option value="Evening">Evening</option>
</select>
```

On tab of First field I am removing 'input-valication-error' class from 2nd field and on Shift+tab from last field I am suppose to do the same thing as I don't need validation on 2nd field on tab or shift+tab
The JQuery Code is written as follows:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js")" type="text/javascript">`</script>

    $("#AltPhone").blur(function () {
      $(this).removeClass('input-validation-error');
      $("label[for='AltPhone']").removeClass('input-validation-error');
    });

    $('#AltPhone').live('focus', function (event) {
       $(window).keyup(function (event) {
         var code = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
         if (code == 9 || event.shiftKey) {
         $("#AltPhone").removeClass('input-validation-error');
         $("label[for='AltPhone']").removeClass('input-validation-error');
             }
     });
    });
```

**The result that I am getting is that on tab its working smooth but on shift+tab its like appearing red(shows validation) and after some fraction of microsecond turns into white(validation disappears)**

Comment: `.removeClass('input-validation-error')` is not going to prevent validation (just hide the error from displaying) so its unclear what your really trying to achieve with this. And `.live()` was depreciated in v1.7 and removed in `v1.9` so you might want to consider upgrading your scripts.

Comment: Here I am not trying to hide the error as the box itself getting turned into red and as far as .live concerned yes I can use rather .bind

Comment: Yes I know, but what are you trying to achieve with this? Just removing the red border wont do anything to prevent validation occurring (your model will still be invalid)